# Appending nested dictionary objects to a list based on the values of the nested dictionary object. PYTHON

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I've come across an issue with some code I'm writing to display a list of objects that the user can select from. Each object has a given 'Size' attached to it, and each time an object is selected, that size is subtracted from the maximum allowable amount of objects the user can select.

Basically, user starts with an amount limit of 5.
Each object has a size ranging from 1 to 4.

When the user first makes a selection, there are no restrictions, but after that, what the list should show is limited to objects under what amount they have left, so they shouldn't see any objects with a 'Size' of 3, if they only have an amount limit of 2 remaining.

So far, my existing code works for everything except putting those limitations in place.

```
set1_items = {
    "Option1": {
        "Common": [
            {"Item Name": "A1", "Size": 3},
            {"Item Name": "A2", "Size": 4}
        ],
        "Uncommon": [
            {"Item Name": "B1", "Size": 2},
            {"Item Name": "B2", "Size": 1}
        ]
    },
    "Option2": {
        "Common": [
            {"Item Name": "C1", "Size": 3},
            {"Item Name": "C2", "Size": 1}
        ],
        "Uncommon": [
            {"Item Name": "D1", "Size": 2},
            {"Item Name": "D2", "Size": 4}
        ]
    }
}

chosen_objects = []

objects_chosen = None
max_amount_limit = 5
selected_objects_size = 0
available_objects_list = []

while objects_chosen is None:
    if (max_amount_limit - selected_objects_size) > 3:
        available_objects_list = set1_items["Option1"]["Common"]
    elif (max_amount_limit - selected_objects_size) <4:
        available_objects_list = set1_items["Option1"]["Common"]?????

    object_availability = available_objects_list
    objects_itr = 0
    for i in object_availability:
        print(object_itr, end=' - ')
        for key, val in i.items():
            print(key, ": ", val, end='\n    ')
        print()
        object_itr = object_itr+1

    chosen_object_index = input("> ")
    chosen_object_index = int(chosen_object_index)
    chosen_objects.append(object_availability[chosen_object_index]["Item Name"]

    selected_objects_size = selected_objects_size + object_availability[chosen_object_index]["Size"]

    if max_amount_limit == selected_objects_size:
        objects_chosen = "Done"
    else:
        continue_object_selection = input("""
You have """+str(int(max_amount_limit - selected_objects_size))+""" amounts left.

Do you want to select more objects from Set 1, or move on to Set 2?
1 - Continue with Set 1
2 - Move on to Set 2

>""")

        if continue_object_selection == "1":
            objects_chosen is None
        elif continue_object_selection == "2":
            objects_chosen - "Done"
        else:
            print("Not a valid choice, try again")
```

This is a basic, trimmed down version of my code, and I've added ????? where the code is in need of something more.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I haven't been able to find anything regarding appending nested dictionary items to a list based on their values.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are there Uncommon objects, but they get ignored?  Should this keep looping until the user fills the allocation (or chooses done), or should it allow a max of one item from each Set?

Comment: Wait, your WHILE loop is an infinite loop. Please make your code both Minimal and actually run; [mre]

Comment: The WHILE loop does close at the bottom. And this is just a tiny portion of my code that contains enough info to demonstrate what I'm talking about. The Uncommon items get ignored in this code because I only want to populate the list with Common items. And yes, it should keep looping until the user fills up their allocation or chooses done.

Comment: Then your indentations are wrong. There are only 4 lines in your WHILE loop as written. Please correct your code so that it can be copy pasted and still run.

Comment: The loop condition is `while objects_chosen is None`.  The four lines of code in the loop body do not modify `objects_chosen`, so yes, this is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question's example code doesn't run, but I think the only thing you're asking about is how to filter a nested dictionary.

If so, I'd use comprehensions.

```
filtered = {
  option: {
    rarity: [
      item for item in items
        if item["Size"] <= max_amount_limit
    ]
      for rarity, items in options.items() 
  } 
    for option, options in set1_items.items() 
}
```

Demo : https://trinket.io/python3/5c8666dcce

***Edit: Examples for filtering rarity too, either dynamically or hard coded...***

```
filtered = {
  option: {
    rarity: [
      item for item in items
        if item["Size"] <= max_amount_limit
    ]
      for rarity, items in options.items()
        if rarity == 'Common'
  } 
    for option, options in set1_items.items() 
}
```

Or...

```
filtered = {
  option: [
      item for item in options['Common']
        if item["Size"] <= max_amount_limit
  ]
    for option, options in set1_items.items() 
}
```

Demo: https://trinket.io/python3/5835bd66c1

Comment: I'm also trying to filter out the Uncommon items too. How would that fit into this? (Comprehensions are completely new to me)

Comment: @MoonlyteDemon Comprehensions are essentially just for loops where the results are bundled together into an iterable / generator.  `[ foo(x) for x in y if bar(x) ]` loops through `y` putting the items in `x` one at a time, checks `bar(x)` and if it's True, yields `foo(x)`, then moves on to the next item in `y`, packaging all the True results into a List... `[` `foo(x)` `for x in y` `if bar(x)` `]`

Comment: This is looking promising, however, something about this addition to the code seems to be overwriting something in the for loop to display the objects ---

for i in object_availability:
        print(object_itr, end=' - ')
        for key, val in i.items():

--- I'm getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' for the for key, val in i.items(): line on the second pass through the while loop, which sounds like a dictionary has been turned into a string?

Comment: The example you chose ***removes*** the rarities layer *(as there would only ever one key, and it would always be `'Common'`)* Print the filtered dictionary out to see what it looks like. If that doesn't help, open a new question.